# Hide dynamically inputs and label

Tags: angular

I've an html with a lot of inputs and labels. I want to hide or make visible some fields if the text of a select option is"Accept".

I've this:

```
  <label for="result">Result</label><br/>
  <select formControlName="result" (change)="searchValues()">
    <option *ngFor="let result of result" >{{result.description}}</option>
  </select><br/><br/>

  <label for="resultreason" hidden>Rejection</label><br/>
  <select formControlName="resultreason" >
    <option *ngFor="let resultreason of resultreason" >{{resultreason.description}}</option>
  </select><br/><br/>
```

What I want is: if in result the choice is Accept, I want to hide the label "resultreason". And if result is not Accept, make it visible.

I've readed about doing it with ngif or ngshow, but I have not succeeded. I also tried doing it in the component, but nothing :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Change  searchValues to (change)="searchValues($event)"
Add

```
showReason = true;


searchValues({value}) {
  this.showReason = value !== 'accept';
}
```

Add this in your class compoenent

In your Html

```
<div *ngIf="showReason">
  <label for="resultreason" hidden>Rejection</label><br/>
  <select formControlName="resultreason" >
    <option *ngFor="let resultreason of resultreason" >{{resultreason.description}}</option>
  </select><br/><br/>
</div>
```

Hope useful

Comment: Thanks A.Khalifa. When I try to put   @ViewChild('id')  el:ElementRef;, I've this error: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1

Comment: i think it's better to not use ViewChild.

Comment: @Unai you need to add static like this @ViewChild('id', {static: false})

Comment: in new version, @ViewChild('xxx', { static: boolean })
however, i just recommended to not use it as it can be solved without much typing :D

Comment: @RobertB. i'm with you but imagine if i want to add a lot of css style

Comment: just define a class with all styles you want.
and 
```
<div *ngIf="showReason" ngClass="{yourClass: showReason}">
```

Comment: @RobertB. Ok great answer but ngIf and ngClass can create performance problems

Comment: include `display: none` in `yourClass` then, and remove `*ngIf`

Comment: Ok @RobertB. great discussion  ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this without using another variable in typescript, by getting value from form control

Rejection